# Getting all the values out of a field as array of values

Tags: templating, field, plugin-elementapi, json

I have a multi-select field in my work section

[image]

I want to get the values either with the Element api as json or an array of simple values in my template.

Comment: Do you want every possible value for the field? Or all of the selected values for the field on an element (i.e. entry, user, etc.).

Comment: Hi Brad, every value.

Answer (score 1):

`$element->getFieldValue('handle')` or it's Twig equivalent `element.handle` contains an Object of type `MultiOptionsFieldData` you can get all possible values via it`s`getOptions()` function

#### Twig

```
{{ dump(entry.fieldHandle.getOptions()) }}
```

#### PHP

```
$options = $element->getFieldValue('handle')->getOptions();
```